# Flex TabNavigator null object issue

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, tabnavigator

I am having trouble with TabNavigator that it always dispatch error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mx.containers::TabNavigator/keyDownHandler()[/Users/justinmclean/Documents/ApacheFlex4.11.0/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/containers/TabNavigator.as:903]
```

Example code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="init(event)">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handleKeyDown);
        }

        public function handleKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.F1){
                if(currentState=="State1"){
                    currentState = "setting";
                }else{
                    currentState = "State1";
                }
            }
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="State1"/>
    <s:State name="setting"/>
</s:states>

<s:BorderContainer left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" includeIn="setting">
<mx:TabNavigator id="TabNavigator" left="10" right="10" top="110" bottom="10" creationPolicy="all">
    <!-- General Tab -->
    <s:NavigatorContent id="generaltab" width="100%" height="100%" label="General">
        <s:Group id="generalcontainer">
        </s:Group>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <!-- Screen Tab -->
    <s:NavigatorContent id="screentab" width="100%" height="100%" label="Screen">
        <s:Group id="screencontainer" width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:Group>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <!-- Playlist Tab -->
    <s:NavigatorContent id="playlisttab" width="100%" height="100%" label="Playlist">
        <s:Group id="playlistcontainer">    
        </s:Group>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:TabNavigator>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

When I press on F1, it will jump to setting page. Which will show the tabnavigator. Press F1 again to hide it.

Basically, there is no problem to show and hide the tab navigator repeatedly. But if I clicked any tab before hide the tab navigator, when I try to show the tab navigator again by pressing F1 on keyboard, it dispatch error as I showed above.

How can I solve / prevent the error from occurring?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to prevent the bug from occurring. That is by adding `TabNavigator.stage.focus=null;` before changing the state back to `State1`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've stumbled on a bug in the SDK (which frankly worries me a bit, because it means some event listeners are not being disposed of properly).

Look at the source where the error occurs:

```
override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (focusManager.getFocus() == this)
    {
        // Redispatch the event from the TabBar so that it can handle it.
        tabBar.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

What happens is that when you go from `State1` to `setting`, the `TabNavigator` is initially not on the displayList (you're in the process of adding it through `includeIn`), hence it has no `focusManager`. That's perfectly normal; what is not normal is that the `keyDownHandler` method is executed for a component that is not currently on the displayList. This eventually results in that nullpointer exception because there is no `focusManager` when the method is executed.
It looks like the framework doesn't clean up the event listener when the parent of the TabNavigator is removed. It does work correctly when TabNavigator itself is being added/removed with `includeIn` itself, so luckily for you the workaround is quite simple:

```
<s:BorderContainer includeIn="setting">
    <mx:TabNavigator id="TabNavigator" includeIn="setting" creationPolicy="all">
```

You might want to register this bug in the [Apache Flex JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX)

Comment: Hi RIAstar. Thanks a lot for your explanation. I will submit this bug to Apache Flex JIRA. But in the meantime, do you have any suggestion how can I prevent the bug from occurring? I simply can't wait for the bug fixed to continue the project.

Comment: @user1995781 Well applying `includeIn="setting"` on the TabNavigator itself (as I explained above) worked for me. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I actually miss-read your workaround. Anyway, I just tried it, but it doesn't seems work for me. Maybe it works on the simplified example here, but not on real code. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. :)